# Do we have some inbuild function in python 2.7.9 which gets input both in integer & string using same function

Tags: python, input

I am using python 2.7.9 and also i am new to stack overflow.

`input()` is used for getting integer as input from user.
`raw_input()` is used for getting string as input from user.

I am looking for some common function in python 2.7.9 which will allow user to input either integer or string based up on user wish

I am using below code:

```
A=input("Enter a String")

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/eubcefm/Desktop/Important/Python/2407/Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    A=input("Enter a String")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'And' is not defined
```

Comment: Don't use `input()`. Use `raw_input()` and convert it to an int if appropriate.

Comment: You should use `raw_input()` and cast the resulting string to an `int()` if needed.

Comment: You can do what you want by trying first to parse the raw value using `int(value)` in a try-except block to catch the `ValueError` it will raise if it's not a proper integer, and resort to strings if you cannot parse as `int`. Don't use `input()` in Python 2, it's equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))`, which is bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw_input() and try to convert it to an int.

```
rawinput=raw_input("Enter a String :")
try:
    value=int(rawinput)
except ValueError:
    value=rawinput

print "Type is ", type(value)
print "Value is ", value
```